# one .js to load all .js and .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I need to create a simple javascript embed type thing where the user adds a small amount of javascript to their site and my script does the rest.

This is the sort of thing I would like to see on the user site:

Included once:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/doEverythingScript.js"></script>
```

And this in the HTML:

```
<div id="target-div">    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        doThis(1714581, "#target-div");
    </script> 
</div>
```

I would also need to be able to have multiple versions running on the same page.

The id (eg: 1714581) is passed to my function along with my target div.

This issue is I need to have the one script load all the dependancies:

eg:

```
path/to/style1.css
path/to/style2.css
path/to/style3.css
path/to/jquery.js
path/to/script1.js
path/to/script2.js
path/to/script3.js
path/to/script4.js
```

And once they are all loaded I would then be able to run my function.

If my function ran before they all loaded It naturally wouldn't work.

I tried using LazyLoad and LAB but couldn't work out how to have one JS file sort all this out with only one linkied script and a small function on the page.

What I have writen so far doesnt work becuas the function tries to run before the dependecies are loaded.

Any help with this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: **One .js to load them all**, One .js to find them,
One .js to bring them all and in the darkness bind them
In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let this be your loaded script (configure the first block to meet your wishes). On request of the OP, I've also added a queue function.

Note: Add `_REQUIRED_` instead of an external resource, if you want to delay loading additional scripts until the previously requests has been finished.

```
//@author Rob W. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7698018#7698219

//The "real" doThis. You can define any number of arguments.
function _$doThis(a,b){

}

var rw$loader_queue = []; //Unique name, to prevent messing with the code
function doThis(){rw$loader_queue.push(arguments)}
function _doThisAll(){
    for(var i=0,len=rw$loader_queue.length; i<len; i++){
         //Function.apply: First argument = context (default window)
         // second argument = array of arguments
        _$doThis.apply(null, rw$loader_queue.shift());
    }
}
(function(){//Anonymous function = no variable leaking
    //Append the scripts.styles to the head, if existent. Otherwise, try body
    var main = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.body;
    var _REQUIRED_ = ((new Date).getTime()*(new Date).getTime()||Math.random()).toString(36);
    /***CONFIGURATION**/
    var nocache = false; //false = allow caching

    /*Usage: initLoad("type",
                      (multidimensional) array | string,
                       optional function: called when initLoad finishes
                     ) */

    initLoad("style", [
      //'sc-player-widget/css/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css',
        'sc-player-widget/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css',
        'sc-player-widget/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectmenu.css', 
        'sc-player-widget/css/sc-player.css',
        'sc-player-widget/colorbox/colorbox.css'
    ]);
    initLoad("script", [
        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js',
         _REQUIRED_,
        'sc-player-widget/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js', 
        'sc-player-widget/js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js', 
        'sc-player-widget/js/ui/jquery.ui.position.js',
        'sc-player-widget/js/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js', 
        'sc-player-widget/js/ui/jquery.ui.button.js',
        'sc-player-widget/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js',
    ], _doThisAll);

    /*END OF CONFIG*/

    function initLoad(type, source, ready){
        var currentSources = source instanceof Array ? source : [source];
        var beforeRequire = 0;
        var paused = false;
        var hasFinished = false;
        var num_resources = 0;
        var load_success = 0;
        next(); //Start walking through the requested resource;

        return;
        function next(){
            if(!currentSources.length){ //End of sources
                if(typeof ready == "string") ready = window[ready];
                if(typeof ready == "function" && !hasFinished) (hasFinished=true) && ready();
                return;
            }
            var current = currentSources.shift();
            if(current === _REQUIRED_){
                if(!currentSources.length) return next();
                paused = true;
                return;
            }
            beforeRequire++;
            num_resources++;
            loadResource(type, current, finished);
            if(currentSources.length) next();
            // If length == 0, wait until the resources have finished loading
        }
        function finished(){
            load_success++;
            if(!--beforeRequire && paused) next();
            else if(num_resources == load_success && !currentSources.length) next();
            //If end of queue, next() = ready()
        }
    }
    function loadResource(type, src, finish){
        if(nocache) src += "?"+(new Date).getTime();
        var s = document.createElement(type=="style"?"link":type);
        var executed = false;
        function oncomplete(){
            if(executed) return;
            executed = true;
            s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = null;
            finish();
        }
        s.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") oncomplete();
        }
        s.onload = oncomplete;
        if(type == "style"){
            s.type = "text/css";
            s.rel = "stylesheet";
            s.href = src;
        } else s.src = src;
        main.appendChild(s);
    }
})();
```

In your HTML source:

```
<script src="path/to/doEverythingScript.js"></script>
...
<script>
    doThis(1714581, "#target-div");
</script>
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need but it's doesnt seem to be working for me.

I added this to the HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript">
function scriptLoaded(){
 alert('ready');
}
</script>`

to test it but no alert.

I also added some .js and .css files to load and when I checked generated source from "developers toolbar" they are not created.

any ideas?

Comment: also...where exactly should I add my functions?

Comment: Thanks Rob, Sorry to seem a little slow but where does my doThis() funtion go?

Also..can I have multiple versions running on the same page.

<script type="text/javascript">
function scriptLoaded(){
    doThis(1714581, "#target-div1");
}
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function scriptLoaded(){
    doThis(5811714, "#target-div2");
}
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function scriptLoaded(){
    doThis(1451781, "#target-div3");
}
</script>

Comment: thanks Rob.... i'm so sorry... I still cant get this to work. Also when looking at the generated source I see the style tags are empty. <style> tags are created but nothing in them.

I created a new .js with my function doThis in it with an alert but no alert so it's seems the function does not run. all the javascript are created though. Any ideas?

Comment: also, do you think @N Rohler's queue idea could be be implemended here for handling the multiple instances? : http://jsfiddle.net/w4UqT/1/

Comment: I've revised my answer. It can now handle multiple instances (I've previously misunderstood you). Also, the style is now correctly loaded.

Comment: OK.... just a few strange things happening. It works then it doesn't. I ran it the first time in FF and it worked... after that if I reload the page or hit refresh it doesn't work... a little different in safari, If I reload the page (click in address bar and hit enter) if works every time but if I hot the refresh button it doesn't. Any ideas about this? Sorry to be a pain. :(

Comment: sorry, seems to be doing the same thing. and other ideas?

Comment: If I change the setting from "on Load" to "no wrap (head)" it works. 
eg: http://jsfiddle.net/SECEg/3/. What does that mean?

Comment: The fiddle wraps the code in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`, by default. This causes the variables and methods to not be definned globally. As a result of this, the function call in the body doesn't work.When you use `no wrap (head)`, the code is included without a wrapper, causing the right methods to be defined globally.

Comment: ok.. that makes sence, thanks. BUT... I still have the same issue mentioned above with refresh and reload. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Have you tried my latest update, including `nocache`? If it doesn't work, replace `src += "?"` by `src += "?_nocache="`.

Comment: Yeah... just grabed it again to be sure. Still the same issue. Also tried the `"?_nocache="` but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide links to your resources, so I can perform tests?

Comment: I think I found the issue... when I replaced my local version of jquery 'js/jquery-1.5.1.js' with the google link 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' everything seems to be working fine. I'll run some more tests and report back.

Comment: ok..the issue is the files dont seem to be loading one after the other... So the first file I load is jquery and the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th are dependent on jquery and are failing because they try to load before jquery. Is it possible to have the script load in the proper execution order? BTW here is a list of the scripts i'm loading:

`jquery.min.js`
`jquery.ui.core.js`
`jquery.ui.widget.js`
`jquery.ui.position.js`
`jquery.ui.selectmenu.js`
`jquery.ui.button.js`
`jquery.colorbox.js`

Comment: I can't reproduce your statements. The scripts are executed in the order of appearance in the configurable array. If you're getting different results, please post full URLs to these external files, for verification.

Comment: i'm running everything localy at the moment. Should i put it online somewhere or zip and upload the files?

Comment: If possible, let your host serve the files. Before doing that, confirm that the files are not loaded in the right order by using the console or HttpFox(FireFox), or the Developer console (Chrome). What browser are you using, by the way?

Comment: Using FF and tested also in Safari. the FF error consol give a `Error: jQuery is not defined` for every file it tries to load accept for the actual jQuery files which loaded correctly. jQuery is loaded first in the script.

Comment: @cybercampbell Updated code, added a new argument `_REQUIRED_`. See answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. getting a strange responce with the new code. I simplified the `doThis` function to just `alert(a +" | "+ b);`. Please take a look. it should only alert the 4 times it's called but it does more and undefinded. thanks

Comment: Actually... it seems to only be FF that is behaving like that.

Comment: Applied a patch. I've successfully tested the code, with the latest modifications (FF 7).

Comment: Hi @Rob W , I am getting errors in IE and issues (but no errors) in FF 3.4. This is the error IE gives: `Line: 242
Character: 13
Code: 0
Error Message: Object doesn't support this property or method` Any ideas?

Comment: also, If I only have one script in the script array it doesn't run the function.

Comment: @cybercampbell I've applied some fixes. I guess that you're using IE8-? For some reason, IE didn't support `Array.indexOf` until version 9.

Comment: Thanks for that. All working in IE now. (BTW IE NEVER my browser of choice.) I little thing is happening but may not relate to your script is that when I run multipule instances of the `doThis()` function on one page (for example 6) it doesn't run them all. Most of the time is does but I would say on average 2 out of 10 is deosn't. It will only run the first two. Also, If it doesn't run them all (example only ran twice) if I click into the address bar and hit enter it will continue only running the two previously but if I hit refresh it most of the time will run them all. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: ok.. I think it is to do with the script. For testing purposes I run it only once on my page. I put an `alert()` on the first line of the .js and it alerted every load or refresh. I put the `alert()` on the first line of the `doThis()` function and it alerted every time. I then put the `alert()` on the first line of the `_$doThis()` function and it did not alert everytime. Do you know why it's doing that? Thanks C

Comment: Can you provide a live test case, preferrably the real (production) page? I'm going to check the headers of the loaded resources.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using document.write() to insert new `<script>` and `<style>` tags into the page to load your resources?

Comment: LazyLoad and LAB took care of that side of things and they even have a callback to run stuff after they complete the loading but my function is called from the users page when the page is loaded.

That's where the issue lies.

Comment: so you are saying that `doThis()` is executed before the script file defining `doThis()` is loaded? In that case you need to fire some sort of event when all the resources are loaded, and have the user call `doThis()` only when that event is fired - a la document.ready

Comment: @mattb @cybercampbell Or, in the `doEverythingScript.js` file, define `doThis()` as a function that creates a queue.  Later, when all of the other assets finish loading, have the real method process that queue.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/w4UqT/1/

Comment: Thanks for the Queue idea... do you think this could be added the Rob W's script below?